# Graph ggplot with geom_jitter - what does the jitter tell us?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I do have one question regarding the jitter plot function. It is a nice way to plot point for different categories and avoid overlapping. But what does the exact distance between the points tell us?
I would appreciate an answer a lot.
Thank you in advance!

[image: click here for image of graph]

Code:

```
# Visualisation in grid
#Workday alcohol consumption per school
DFV1 <- ggplot(data.source1, aes(x=dalc, y=school, color=sex))+geom_jitter(alpha=0.7)+scale_colour_manual(values=c("#ff7f50", "#468499"))+theme_bw()+xlab("Workday alcohol consumption")+ylab("School")+ggtitle("Workday alcohol consumption per school and sex")

#Weekend alcohol consumption per school
DFV2 <- ggplot(data.source1, aes(x=walc, y=school, color=sex))+ geom_jitter(alpha=0.7)+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("#ff7f50", "#468499"))+theme_bw()+xlab("Weekend alcohol consumption")+ylab("School")+ggtitle("Weekend alcohol consumption per school and sex")

#set grid
(Package gridExtra is needed)
grid.arrange(DFV1,DFV2, nrow=2)
```

Comment: The horizontal point distance is arbitrary. The jitter is just random. This is why one should use a beeswarm plot here, instead.

Answer (score 0):

That distance is specified in the `width` and `height` arguments. From the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html):

> If omitted, defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data: this means the jitter values will occupy 80% of the implied bins

So the distance does not tell you anything about the data.